# Orchard 1.10.1 on Azure installation

Tags: azure, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I set up a new AppService on Azure along with an empty database.

I downloaded and opened Orchard 1.10.1 in Visual Studio 2015.  I right click the solution and rebuild. After that completes I right click Orchard.Web and publish. I downloaded the publish profile and loaded it into VS2015 during the publish process for the Orchard.Web.

The publish process completes successfully and opens a new browser window. After it compiles it only loads a white page with message:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /

[image: VS_screenshot]

Comment: It sounds that you do not have set the right database string in your settings.txt file.

Comment: Yes, check the log files in App_Data/Logs. This typically is a DB connection issue.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. When I look into the file structure on the remote server The App_Data folder is empty. I searched for settings.txt with no result. I looked in all the config files I saw and didn't see a connection string. I am going to try Pete's suggestion down below

Answer (score 0):

If there are no orchard logs in `site\wwwroot\App_Data\Logs`, then you can check the event view logs to see if there is anything there which might be logged outside of the Orchard app:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/07/01/how-to-view-the-event-logs-of-your-azure-app-service/

Otherwise, rather than VS publish, you could try a console build and FTP?

Execute: `msbuild Orchard.proj /t:Precompiled /v:m /m`

Then upload the `\build\Precompiled` folder to `site\wwwroot`

If this is a new site you should actually hit the setup page to paste in the connection string to initialize the empty database. Also this method should startup reasonably quickly as there will be no compilation done on the server.

Comment: Again, thank you for your insight Pete. OI really appreciate the detailed execute and file location you provided. I will give that a try when I get home after work and report back